# batch rename file extensions in subdirectories

Tags: shell, unix, automation, busybox

I'm trying to create a batch file in linux that will allow me to change extensions of files in multiple subdirectories. After much searching and experimenting i've found what seems to be a solution:

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" -exec rename .mkv .avi {} +
```

When running the script i get the following error:

```
find: -exec CMD must end by ';'
```

I've tried adding ; and \; (with or without +) but to no avail. What's wrong with the command and how can I fix it?

Edit: Running on a Synology NAS with DSM 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to escape all characters that would be interpreted by `bash`. in your case these are the semicolon and the *curly braces* (you forgot to escape the latter in your code):

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" -exec rename .mkv .avi \{\} \;
```

the `{}` (in our case `\{\}`) is expanded to the filename, so the actual call would look like `rename .mkv .avi /volume1/uploads/foo/bla.mkv` (which is not the exact syntax the `/usr/bin/rename` needs, at least on my system).
instead it would be something like:

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" -exec rename 's/\.mkv$/.avi/' \{\} \;
```

### UPDATE

if you don't want to (or cannot) use perl's `rename` script, you could use the following simple bash script and save it as /tmp/rename.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
INFILE=$1
OUTFILE="${INFILE%.mkv}.avi"
echo "moving ${INFILE} to ${OUTFILE}"
mv "${INFILE}" "${OUTFILE}"
```

make it executable (`chmod u+x /tmp/rename.sh`) and call:

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" -exec /tmp/rename.sh \{\} \;
```

### UPDATE2

it turned out that this question is really not about `bash` but about `busybox`.

with a limited shell interpreter like busybox, the simplest solution is just to *append* the new file extension:

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" -exec mv \{\} \{\}.avi \;
```

Comment: Running find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" gives me all the files I'm interested in, but when escaping the curly braces and semicolon I get the following error (for each file found): find: rename: No such file or directory

Comment: well, it was your example code that used `rename` and i assumed that you knew how to use it (and that it was actually there). the `-exec` flag will just take a binary and run it, so you obviously have to make sure that you have a `rename` binary on your system. here (on a debian/sid box) it comes with `perl`. anyhow, i'll update the answer to use a small example script that fits your needs

Comment: As you might have guessed I'm a complete n00b when it somes to shell scripts. I appreciate the help! I've followed your update (creating a second file, chmod and run from first file) but I get another error: "No such file or directory" for each found file.

Comment: did you give the *full path* of the rename-script to `find`? if not, you probably should; if you did, i have updated the script a little bit so it makes some printout to tell you what it is about to do. maybe you can guess from that printout what goes wrong.

Comment: It keeps giving the file not found error, so I've tried running the rename function (file 2) directly in the command after -exec. This gives a new error: "Not a directory" (it appends the filename with a / )

Comment: what does `/tmp/rename.sh /flub.mkv` print?

Comment: Running the command "sh tmp/rename.sh /flub.mkv" gives:
.avi/flub.mkvmkv
': No such file or directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32683/discussion-between-roland-and-umlaeute)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how different `find` and `rename` commands are on your DSM 4.2 OS so try something like:

```
find /volume1/uploads -name "*.mkv" | while read filename; 
do mv -v "${filename}" "$(echo "${filename}" | sed -e 's/\.mkv$/\.avi/')"
done
```